# How to make everything null when there is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want values to be null if there is any null in particular group.
 When I am using aggregate functions, ie sum, then it is handling null itself but I don't want to handle null, I need null should make null when doing sum on it.

```
declare @tbl table (id int,grpid char )

insert into @tbl
values(1,'a'), (2,'b'),(null,'b')

select grpid,sum(id) as val
from @tbl
group by grpid
```

required output :

```
grpid    val 
a           1
b          null
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple as this I guess...

```
declare @tbl table (id int,grpid char )

insert into @tbl
values(1,'a'), (2,'b'),(null,'b')


;WITH cte AS(
SELECT DISTINCT grpid
  FROM @tbl
  WHERE id IS NULL
)
select t.grpid,sum(id) as val
from @tbl t
WHERE grpid NOT IN (SELECT grpid FROM cte)
GROUP BY t.grpid
UNION
SELECT grpid, NULL
  FROM cte
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try these methods:

**Method 1:**

```
select grpid,
       case 
        when count(*)<>count(id) then null 
        else sum(id) 
       end as val
from @tbl
group by grpid
```

**Note:** `Count(*)` always return the number of records but `Count(ColumnName)` always return the number of records where **ColumnName is not null**

**Method 2:**

```
select grpid,
       case 
        when exists(Select top 1 * from @tbl where grpid = t.grpid and id is null) then null
        else sum(id) 
       end as val
from @tbl as t
group by grpid
```

**Method 3:**

```
select grpid, sum(id) as val
from @tbl as t
where grpid NOT IN (Select grpid from @tbl where id is null)
group by grpid 
union
select grpid , null as val from @tbl where id is null
```

Comment: Method 1 is probably the best, since it's the simplest. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
declare @tbl table (id int, grpid char );

insert into @tbl
values (1,'a'), (2,'b'), (null,'b'), (3, 'a'), (null, 'c');

select t1.grpid 
     , case when t2.grpid is null then sum(t1.id) 
            else null 
       end as 'ssum'
from @tbl t1
left join @tbl t2 
  on t2.grpid = t1.grpid 
 and t2.id is null
group by t1.grpid, t2.grpid
order by t1.grpid;
```

Similar to some existing but might be more efficient
`UNION` will perform a distinct

```
declare @tbl table (id int, grpid char );

insert into @tbl
values (1,'a'), (2,'b'), (null,'b'), (3, 'a'), (null, 'c');

with cte as 
( select id, grpid
  from @tbl 
  where id is null
)

select grpid, id
from cte 
union 
select grpid, sum(id) as val 
from @tbl
where not exists (select 1 from cte where cte.grpid = [@tbl].grpid)
group by grpid
order by grpid;
```